# Dependency does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.6, Visual Studio 2015.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a .Net class library in .Net Core Visual Studio 2015.3: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MD.PersianDateTime.Core/

`Project.json` of above package :

```
{
  "authors": [ "Mohammad Dayyan" ],
  "copyright": "By Mohammad Dayyan, 0903-3339923",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },
  "description": "C# library to use PersianCalendar as easy as DateTime",
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "licenseUrl": "http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html",
  "name": "MD.PersianDateTime.Core",
  "title": "PersianDateTime",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "xmlDoc": true
  }
}
```

Now, I want to use it in another .Net Core Class library, with the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "MD.PersianDateTime.Core": "1.0.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "name": "Another .Net Core Class Library",
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

but I get the following errors in compile:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1002  The dependency MD.PersianDateTime.Core 1.0.0.1 does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.6.    SmartizCore C:\Works\SmartizCore\src\SmartizCore\project.json   7
```

**Edit:**
I installed latest version of .Net Core SDK and Runtime from the following link:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc4-download.md
So my .Net Core version is as the following :
[image: .Net Core version in CMD]
But in visual studio I get the following version
[image: .Net Core version in VS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.26206.0
It works without any problems.

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5755

Answer (score 1):

Update your dotnet core version to latest **(Latest version) ---> [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current)**

[image]

then you also need to update this version number in global.json

```
 "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
```

Comment: I installed latest version of Windows SDK & runtime, But I get `1.0.0-preview2-003156` again !!!

Comment: I already added link for latest update.. click on latest and get the most latest version.

Comment: Are these installers for `Visual Studio 2017 RC`? I have VS2015.3 as wrote in main post

Comment: I update the answer please check. SDK version same for all visual studio versions. only Visual Studio tools specific for each version.

Comment: also update your version in project.json as describe here

https://elanderson.net/2016/11/migration-from-asp-net-core-1-0-x-to-1-1/

Answer (score 1):

You should update you .net core version -> [current version](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current)

Make sure to click the “Current” button to see the .NET Core 1.1 download links.

Comment: I downloaded and installed `Current` latest version of Window SDK & runtime installer, But I get `1.0.0-preview2-003156` again !!! and I get the error again.